# What is the command to transpose line from point till end of line?

Tags: commands

Is there a emacs command to tranpose the line from the point till end of the line. For example:

```
quick brown fox jumps over **<point>** the lazy dog meaning
```

After transpose it should be

```
the lazy dog meaning **<point>** quick brown fox jumps over
```

Comment: `C-k C-a C-y` is quick to do: I've never felt the need to have a special command for such a (fairly uncommon IME) operation.

Comment: Wow. Never thought of this way. I used to do the same with 5 key combinations C-SPC C-e C-w C-a C-y. Thanks this definitely helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any built-in functions, but here's a quick & dirty one:

```
(defun my/transpose-line-around-point (p)
  "Transpose text preceding line around POINT."
  (interactive "d")
  (let ((line-beginning (save-excursion (beginning-of-line-text) (point)))
    (line-end (save-excursion (end-of-line) (point))))
    (transpose-regions line-beginning p p line-end)))
```

It could be tweaked to handle spaces better when whitespace comes between the point and some text preceding the end of line.